# Написать xPath-запрос к html-документу

Tags: xpath, html, запрос

Всем привет.
Мучаюсь с простой но непонятной мне вещью.
Как будет выглядеть `XPath`-запрос к `html`-документу, содержащий ссылки такого вида:

```
<a href=“likeview.php?id=6026”>
<a href=“likeview.php?id=584”>
<a href=“likeview.php?id=0128”>
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо так

```
//a[contains(@href, 'likeview.php')]
```

Но в целом, нужно смотреть на весь документ в целом. Возможно, есть куда более простые способы.

Comment: Мне только что подсказали. Вот так заработало.
//a[@href[contains(., "likiview.php?id=")]]
Спасибо Вам.